# get eigenvalue from image using opencv

Tags: opencv, eigenvalue

how I can get eigenvalue from input image using Open CV?
I need that eigenvalue to process poses from my image. when I get eigenvalue from image, I will put it in to my database. after that I could compute eigenvalue from real time camera so I can compare that eigenvalue and can know about what poses the user is shown. please help me.
I don't know how difficulty this process.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want the eigenvalues of the image, just convert to float, and use [eigen()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#eigen) .

but, reading between the lines of your question, it sounds more like you want something like eigenfaces, pose recognition from images, or such ?

in that case, better read up on PCA, and look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html).

Comment: could you give me source or link website where I can learn about it. i have see your link website, but it's not tell me much. please help